# Overriding permissions of existing page blocks all users

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

**Problem**

I'm trying to block access to Drupal's taxonomy pages for anonymous users.

I'm using the solution set out in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38959/how-can-i-prevent-anonymous-users-from-accessing-taxonomy-pages), but for Drupal 7 rather than 6.

I'm using `hook_menu_alter` and `hook_permission` to create a new access argument for taxonomy pages. The permission is successfully created, but no matter what roles I tick the pages remain blocked. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Example Code**

```
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%']['access arguments'] = array('access taxonomy permission');
}

function custom_module_permission() {
  return array(
    'access taxonomy permission' => array(
        'title' => t('Access taxonomy pages'),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason that you're using 'taxonomy/term/%' instead of 'taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term' in your implementation of `hook_menu_alter()`? If not, I would change that and clear the cache, see if it helps.

*Edit*...Here's a code example from the **[Term Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_per_role)** module:

```
function term_per_role_menu_alter(&$items) { 
  $path = 'taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term'; 
  if (isset($items[$path])) { 
    $items[$path]['page arguments'] = array_merge($items[$path]['page arguments'], array($items[$path]['page callback'])); 
    $items[$path]['page callback'] = 'term_per_role_taxonomy_term_page'; 
  } 
}
```

(A module which I would have recommended but the last commit on the project was over 3 years ago.)